# Grunt CasperJS not passing querystring parameters on click

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, casperjs

I have a CasperJS test something like below:

```
casper.test.begin('Testing Querystrings', function suite(test) {

    casper.start()

        .thenOpen('http://www.example.com', function () {
            //
        })

        .then(function () {
            this.click('.target a'); // links to http://www.example.com/page.html?q=test
        })

        .then(function () {
            this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl()); // should output http://www.example.com/page.html?q=test
        })

        .run(function () {
            test.done();
        });
});
```

When I run this using the command line:

```
casperjs test test.js
```

Then everything runs fine and getCurrentUrl() shows the URL with the querystring

I want to run the tests with Grunt however and have set everything up using [grunt-casperjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-casperjs)

When I run the the test via Grunt then the test runs OK but the URL is output without the query string.

I really need this query string to be included so I can run some actual tests.

Any ideas why this would be happening or if there is a fix or work around?

Comment: No idea why running through gruntjs would be any different. Check whether the same PhantomJS version is used: `require('utils').dump(phantom.version)`. Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction. External scripts were not loading which was causing problems. Scripts were being blocked due to proxy issues and having grunt-casperjs options set incorrectly. When I changed the option `--proxy="localhost:3128"` to `--proxy=localhost:3128` without quotes it worked OK.